# creating a function like isdigit() in python

Tags: python

Please don't give me the answer just point me in the right direction, thank you. Also, I need to do this without `isdigit()`.

I am trying to create a program that checks all the characters of a string and if any of them are not natural numbers then the program will return `False` otherwise it will return `True`.

This is what i have so far:

```
numbers = ["0123456789"]

if len(str) > 0:
    for i in str:
        if i not in numbers:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I have a few test cases and the problem I'm having is that when I return, the whole program just ends. I need to find a way to include the `else: return True`

Comment: You probably don't want `numbers` as an array of a single string but just the string of numbers. As a hint: you don't want your function to `return True` as soon as it finds a single digit in your string. You need to move your `return True`.

Comment: To add onto the previous comment, take a look at the ascii table

Comment: Your `if len(str) > 0:` is redundant in many ways ... if you want to check something is greater than 0 you can use `if len(str):` ... but if you are wanting to check if a string has length then you can just `if str:` ... but in anycase, there's little need to check ... you can loop over an empty string (there will just be no iterations)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove the numbers from the list as you are comparing each character to all the digits at once i.e `"1" == "0123456789"` , you also need to check every char before returning True:

```
def is_dig(s):
    numbers = "0123456789"  # single iterable of the numbers
    for i in s:
        if i not in numbers:
            return False
    return bool(s) # return outside the loop also catching empty string
```

A more efficient approach would be to use the ord and `all`:

```
def is_dig(s):
    return len(s) > 0 and all(48 <= ord(ch) <= 57 for ch in s)
```

The `ord` of `"0"` is 48 and the ord of "9" is 57 so if the ord of the char falls in that range then you have a digit, if not `all` will short circuit and return False.

Using the ord without `all` and following your own logic would look something like:

```
def is_dig(s):
    if not s: # empty string
        return False
    for ch in s:
        if not 48 <= ord(ch) <= 57:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

numbers = "0123456789"

```
if len(str) > 0:
    for i in str:
        if i not in numbers:
            return False
    return True
```

Thanks Padraic and everyone for the input. @Till Hoffmann your answer was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: This doesn't do what you said it should do for the empty string. "if any of them are not natural numbers then the program will return False" - that doesn't hold for the empty string (vacuously, all of the characters in the empty string are numbers), so it should return True. Your code returns None instead, which isn't even one of the two choices.